# what is .fuse_hidden0000905600000002

Tags: zip, pycharm

I deleted a zip file I prepared wrongly to upload to S3 bucket for a lambda function but when I delete it this file appears and even if I delete it, it keeps reappearing in my Pycharm.

What is it, should I delete it and how do I delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please see this answer: [what is a .fuse_hidden file and why do they exist?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/493198/what-is-a-fuse-hidden-file-and-why-do-they-exist)

It states:

> You can safely ignore .fuse_hiddenXXXX files. It means a file was deleted but there is at least one software which is still using it, so it can't be removed permanently.

> It will be done automatically when the relevant software stops using the file or exists. Such files are always gone after umount/reboot. This is how Linux and any Unix works but only FUSE exposes these files to the user.

Comment: thanks, I don't know how I missed that but please feel free to mark as duplicate.